# Storing data from a python program onto an excel/notepad document

Tags: python, database, storage, export-to-excel

I have made a python program which asks 10 random maths questions and then displays the score at the end I have pasted my program below. I would like to edit/improve my program so that it can store the score for each person and each class and it should be stored in an excel or notepad document. please help me edit the program and also tell me which function would be best for storing this kind of data. Please explain it and make it as simple as you can because I'm a beginner at python so I don't know many functions or programs.

```
import random
def questions():
    name=input("What is your name: ")
    print("Hello there",name,"! Please answer 10 random maths questions for this test!")

    choice = random.choice("+-x")
    finish = False
    questionnumber = 0
    correctquestions = 0

    while finish == False:
        choice = random.choice("+-x")
        if questionnumber < 10 | questionnumber >= 0:
            number1 = random.randrange(1,10)
            number2 = random.randrange(1,10)
            print((number1),(choice),(number2))
            answer=int(input("What is the answer?"))
            questionnumber = questionnumber + 1

            if choice==("+"):
                realanswer = number1+number2
                if answer==realanswer:
                    print("That's the correct answer")
                    correctquestions = correctquestions + 1
                else:
                    print("Wrong answer, the answer was",realanswer,"!")

            if choice==("x"):
                realanswer = number1*number2
                if answer==realanswer:
                    print("That's the correct answer")
                    correctquestions = correctquestions + 1
                else:
                    print("Wrong answer, the answer was",realanswer,"!")

            elif choice==("-"):
                realanswer = number1-number2

                if answer==realanswer:
                    print("That's the correct answer")
                    correctquestions = correctquestions + 1
                else:
                    print("Wrong answer, the answer was",realanswer,"!")
        else:
            finish = True
    else:
            print("Good job",name,"! You have finished the quiz")
            print("You scored " + str(correctquestions) + "/10 questions.")

questions()
```

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html for writing to a csv file which can be opened in e.g. excel or by other spreadsheet software.

Answer (score 2):

The most simple way to write to an excel file is:

```
score="20"
f = open('example.csv','w')
f.write(score)
f.close()
```

You can also use `xlwt` library to create a new workbook object which can be populated with information.

```
score=20
name="Mark"

import xlwt
book = xlwt.Workbook(encoding="utf-8")
sheet1 = book.add_sheet("Sheet 1") 
sheet2 = book.add_sheet("Sheet 2") 
sheet1.write(0, 0, str(score))             #write score to cell(0,0) in Sheet 1
sheet1.write(0, 1, name)                   #write name to cell(0,0) in Sheet 1
book.save('book3.xls')                     #the workbook will be saved as "book3.xls" in your working directory
```

To rewrite to the same workbook, you may use this:

```
score2=40
name2="Peter"

from xlrd import *
w = copy(open_workbook('book3.xls'))
w.get_sheet(0).write(1,0,str(score2))        #write score to cell(1,0) in Sheet 1
w.get_sheet(0).write(1,1,name2)              #write name to cell(1,1) in Sheet 1
w.save('book3.xls')
```

The resulting excel file looks like this:

```
#20 Mark
#40 Peter
```

Answer (score 0):

For notepad:

```
scores = {"name_1" : 10, "name_2" : 20, "name_3" : 30}      # your score data
my_file = open('scores.txt', 'w')                           # create the file
for name in scores:                                         # the loop
    my_file.write(name + ": " + str(scores[name]) + "\n")   # write score line by line
my_file.close()                                             # close the file
```

For excel, use [xlsxwriter](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/):

```
import xlsxwriter
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('scores.xlsx')          # create the workbook
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()                   # add a sheet
scores = {"name_1" : 10, "name_2" : 20, "name_3" : 30} # your score data
i = 0                                                  # line index
for name in scores:                                    # the loop
    worksheet.write(i, 0, name)                        # write name at line i and column 0
    worksheet.write(i, 1, scores[name])                # write score at line i and column 1
    i += 1                                             # increment the line index
workbook.close()                                       # close the workbook
```

Install xlsxwriter using pip:

> pip install xlsxwriter